# Repositioning pagenumber field in the pager of a jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using  **jqgrid** in my cshtml page. The problem is that the area for grid is narrow, and so I want the page number field in the pager of grid to appear somewhere else in the page near the grid. I need relocating the page number field only, not the pager itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***page number*** field is a part of the pager itself and so cannot be separated from the same. But there is a workaround for this. You can set the variable `pginput` to false as given on the [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)  . It determines if the input box, where the user can change the number of the requested page, should be available. So on setting false it will not appear to the user. Using the code given below, you can get the current page number of the grid and set into any text box defined by you on the page.

```
$('#your_grid').getGridParam('page'); // get current page
```

When user changes the page number, all you need to do is set the page number using code below.

```
$('#your_grid').setGridParam({page:value}).trigger('reloadGrid'); // set page to grid and reload. value is the page number to be set
```

This code should be handled within keydown function of the text box defined by you to hold the page number.